# How to get string name from other string in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I am developing a SMS Software, I want to give Option to Customer to define their own SMS.

I give them a text box to write their own SMS which can include database field names
Like 
Dear Customer +`CustName`+ Thank you for visiting Here, Your Bill Amount is : +`BillTotal`+
CustName And BillTotal is Database Field name and Customer add All Other Field Name which I Show Him to Include.

I want to get Field name from String and fill its value and send SMS to Customer.

Comment: Post your progress. It will be helpful.

Comment: Suggestion: don't use `+`, instead use placeholders like `"Dear customer [CustName], .."`. And then search for words in `[ ]`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can achieve this like

```
string message = string.format("Dear Customer {0} Thank you for visiting Here, Your Bill Amount is : {1}.", txtCustomerName.Text, txtBillAmt.Text);
```

If these values are in varialble then you can do like this-

```
string message = string.format("Dear Customer {0} Thank you for visiting Here, Your Bill Amount is : {1}.", customerName, billAmt);
```

Hope this will work for you..!

Comment: This will not work if customer will write "Your balance is {0}", or if customer will not use value of balance at all in the text. Then exception will be thrown

Answer (score 0):

For the start you can use `String.Split` method

```
string customerText = 
"Dear Customer +CustName+ Thank you for visiting Here, Your Bill Amount is : +BillTotal+";

  string[] splitResult = text.Split('+');

  StringBuilder finalText = New StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < splitResult.Count; i++)
  {
      string originText = splitresult[i];
      if(i % 2 == 0)
          finalText.Append(originText)
      else // odd index - keyword to replace
          finalText.Append(YourMethodToGetValueFromDatabaseByKey(origintext));
  }

  Console.WriteLine(finalText.ToString()); //Print result
```

Of course you will need to advise customer to not use `'+'` character in the normal text. Or use some other "rare" character for this purpose.

Another approach can be using Regex, which I skip in the answer, because not very good with it

Answer (score 0):

To create the SMS string, enclose your Kewords in some delimiters. Here I'm taking `{...}` for example. So whenever the user clicks on any of the keyword buttons, you insert that keyword enclosed in your delimiters.

e.g.

```
  Dear {CustName}, Thank you for visiting Here. Your Bill Amount is : {BillTotal}
```

Next, you need to have a dictionary of Keywords and their corresponding values. Lets call it `KeywordLookup`.

Assuming that `KeywordLookup` dictionary is already filled and has all the values the user can insert into the SMS, the following function will get you the final SMS from the SMS template the user created:

```
string getFinalSMSString(string smsTemplate) 
{
    string result = smsTemplate;
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(smsTemplate, @"{(\w+\s*\w*?)}"))
    {
        string keyword = m.Groups[1].Value;
        if (KeywordLookup.ContainsKey(keyword))
        {
            result = result.Replace(m.Value, KeywordLookup[keyword]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Demo Usage:**

This is assuming you have a Button (button1) on the form:

```
//-- declared at form level
private Dictionary<string, string> KeywordLookup;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //-- ensure that you have all the keywords & values in the dictionary before calling this method.
    KeywordLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    KeywordLookup.Add("CustName", "Pradeep");
    KeywordLookup.Add("BillTotal", "$100.00");
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //-- demo usage
    var s = "Dear {CustName}, Thank you for visiting Here. Your Bill Amount is : {BillTotal}";
    MessageBox.Show(getFinalSMSString(s));
}
```